# Laravel - How to pass the result of Post Request

Tags: laravel

I have this code I have written and tested. The first phase

> mokkle_test(Request $request)

is working. I have issue with how to pass the result of the request to the second phase

First phase:

```
 public function mokkle_test(Request $request)
{
$telco_match=['name'=>'Icell'];
$telco=Telco::where($telco_match)->first(); 
try{
            $client = new Client();
            $response = $client->request(
                    'POST', $telco->send_call, [
                    'json' => [
                    'msisdn' => $request->msisdn,
                    'username' => $telco->username,
                    'password' => $telco->cpPwd,
                    'text' =>$request->text,
                    'correlator' =>$request->correlator,
                    'serviceid' =>$request->serviceid,
                    'shortcode' => $request->shortcode
                ],
                'headers' => [

                    'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
                ],
                ]
            );


    $noti=new Notification_log();
    $noti->error_message= (string)$response->getBody();

    $noti->save();

            $status = $response->getStatusCode();
             $result = $response->getBody();

             return  $result;
}catch(\Exception $e)
{

  return $e->getMessage();
}      

}
```

... and its working very well.

How do I pass the result of the response into another function shown below.

Second phase:

```
  function subscribe($request,$telco)
 {   
 try{
            $client = new Client();
            $response = $client->request(
                    'POST', $telco->billing_callback_2, [
                    'json' => [
                    'msisdn' => $request->msisdn,
                    'username' => $telco->username,
                    'password' => $telco->password,
                    'amount' =>$request->amount,
                    'shortcode' => $request->shortcode
                ],
                'headers' => [
                    'auth' => $telco->authorization,
                    'key' => $telco->key,
                    'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
                ],
                ]
            );

    $amount = $request->amount;
    $shortcode = $request->shortcode;

    $noti=new Notification_log();
    $noti->error_message=(string)$response;
    $noti->msisdn=$request->msisdn;
    $noti->product_id=$request->productid;
    $noti->save();

            $status = $response->getStatusCode();
             $result = $response->getBody();
             $request = array();
             $request->text= "Weldone";
             $request->amount = $amount;
             $request->serviceid="100010";
             $request->correlator="876543ghj";
             $result_sms=self::mokkle_test($request); 
             return  $result;
}catch(\Exception $e)
{    
  return $e;
}                   
}
```

I tried this, but nothing is happening

> $result_sms=self::mokkle_test($request);

Kindly assist. How do I achieve my goal. Kindly assist me.

Comment: Do you want to pass the `Request $request` to `function subscribe` as a parameter? that's it? I'll put inside `public function mokkle_test` this: `this.subscribe($request);` that way your 2nd method (2nd phase) will use the `$request` values too.

Comment: Please can you show it to me

Comment: I did it... read my code

Comment: Pass "Request $request" to your subscribe function like "subscribe(Request $request,$telco)" this

Comment: I want to pass $response = $client->request...  in mokkle_test(   ... into   subscribe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can pass it to the other method

```
public function mokkle_test(Request $request)
{
    $telco_match = ['name' => 'Icell'];
    $telco       = Telco::where($telco_match)->first();
    try {
        $client   = new Client();
        $response = $client->request(
            'POST', $telco->send_call, [
                'json'    => [
                    'msisdn'     => $request->msisdn,
                    'username'   => $telco->username,
                    'password'   => $telco->cpPwd,
                    'text'       => $request->text,
                    'correlator' => $request->correlator,
                    'serviceid'  => $request->serviceid,
                    'shortcode'  => $request->shortcode
                ],
                'headers' => [

                    'Accept'       => 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
                ],
            ]
        );
        // Here you can pass it to the other method
        this.subscribe($response, $telco); // <--- $response will be your "$request" parameter

        $noti                = new Notification_log();
        $noti->error_message = (string)$response->getBody();

        $noti->save();

        $status = $response->getStatusCode();
        $result = $response->getBody();

        return $result;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {

        return $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

Comment: Am sorry please. How will the other end receive it.